# Display image from S3 using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-processing

I have to process very large images (size > 2 GB) stored in aws s3.
Before processing I actually want to display some of them.
Download time is infeasible, is it possible to display them without downloading using **only Python**?

Comment: It is not possible using raw python

Comment: Maybe you could use a free tier EC2 instance (which should have faster and cheaper bandwidth) to downsize prior to downloading and processing...

Comment: You could consider using a third-party service to do the work for you, such as: [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) and [Imgix](http://imgix.com/)

Comment: I would consider performing some kind of batch operation against each image when it is ingested. Create various sized thumbnails, as needed, and store them in S3 with various identifying prefixes, such as thumbs/800/cat.png and thumbs/1024/cat.png.

Answer (score 2):

You could give a URL to the user to open in a web browser. This does involve downloading the image, but it would be done outside of Python.

If you want to present them with a "thumbnail", then you would need a method of converting the image. This could be done with an **AWS Lambda function** that:

- Loads the image into memory (it's too big for the default disk space)
- Resizes the image to a smaller size
- Stores it in Amazon S3
- Provides a URL to the smaller image

This is similar to [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) but it would need a tweak to manipulate the image in memory instead of downloading the image to the Lambda function's disk storage (that is limited to 512MB).